# Looping over items of a jpa streamresult and call an update service. Envers create an revision over all items instead for every single item

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-envers

I loop over person entities of a jpa streamresult and call for every single person an update service bean to update the name of the person entity. I understand, that envers is executed at the end of the transaction. Ok this works fine and all entities are updated and have an AUD table entry, but with a single revision for all.

How I tell spring to do a for every person entity a single transaction , so that envers writes for every updated entity a single update revision instead for all updated person entities? I tried also to put `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` to the top of the update service class, but envers isn't triggered for every item. It seems that all updates are executed in one transaction, but I need a single transacion for every call of the update service bean.

The stream service:

```
@Service
class StreamService {

    @Autowired
    PersonRepository repo;

    @Autowired
    FooService fooService;

    @Transactional
    public void uppercaseAllNames() {
        Stream<Person> stream = repo.findAllPersons();
    
         // change name for each person
        stream.forEach(fooService::doFoo);
    }

}
```

The simplified update service:

```
@Service
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) // <=== create new transaction
class FooService {

    @Autowired
    PersonRepository repo;

    doFoo(Person person) {
        String name = person.getName();
        person.setName(name.toUpperCase());
        repo.save(person); // <=== save trigger envers
    }
}
```

Solution:
The save operation trigger envers to create a revision per person entity, but this solution works in our project only with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`. A single `@Transactional` doesn't work. The annotation can be placed at method  or class level, booth places work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `@Transactional` from `uppercaseAllNames`.
This will give you a separate transactions for the read and each write.

You'll need to add a `personRepo.save(person)` to the `FooService.doFoo` in order to persist the changes.

It might be that the second change is sufficient with `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW`, but I find nested transactions rather confusing and would recommend to avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same Problem and the Accepted Answer above worked. But I had to add `readOnly=true` to the outer Transaction.